# Custom log file from module/controller

Tags: logs

I understand that Craft CMS generates a web.log file for you
but is there a way to do a custom.log?

I have a module and a controller where I want to send specific information from my controller to a custom.log but I can't find any documentation about it.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the Log To File helper, which provides a simple way for logging messages to a specific file: https://github.com/putyourlightson/craft-log-to-file

This question has already been answered in detail at [Craft 3 plugins - Logging in a separate *.log file](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/25427/craft-3-plugins-logging-in-a-separate-log-file)

Comment: Thanks, in fact I tried to use the library but the log was never generated. I am probably using it wrong.

For instance:
``LogToFile :: info ($ message, 'my-plugin-handle');``

What is ``my-plugin-handle``? Because in my case I am not using a plugin, I am using a module.
So if my module is called: custommodule
it is
``LogToFile :: info ($ message, 'custom-module');``

Sorry for the questions but I did see the post but it was not clear to me where you indicate the new name of the .log

Thanks!

Comment: That can be anything, it will be used as the file name for the log file.